# what is the intended underscore name of WEBrick/webrick? (not what do I get with WEBrick.underscore)

Tags: webrick

I am working on a funnel like module, that puts all logging elements together (LogFunnel -> log_funnel).

For that reason I have in application.rb for Rails(.logger)

```
config.log_funnel.rails
```

for ActiveRecord(.logger)

```
config.log_funnel.active_record
```

And so on.

but WEBrick?

underscore "thinks" `we_brick`

I think `web_rick` or even `webrick`

I have no idea what WEB-rick means - WEB seems logic, but rick?

Wht is the intended underscore name of WEBrick?